# How to select all except first element matching criteria using XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have XML like this below. I want to create XPath that will select all nodes except the first "default" node. So in this case, I need to select all but the node with the value "2".

```
<root>
<a default="False">1</a>
<a default="True">2</a>
<a default="False">3</a>
<a default="False">4</a>
<a default="True">5</a>
<a default="False">6</a>
<a default="False">7</a>
</root>
```

Comment: Do you mean select all nodes starting from the second (excluding first)? Or all except the first node with `@default="True"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select all nodes except first one try

```
//a[position() > 1]
```

If you want to select all nodes except the first one that has `@default="True"` try

```
//a[@default="True"][position() != 1]|//a[@default="False"]
```

Comment: That second xpath is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 2.0+, you can use

```
//a except //a[@default='true'][1]
```

(You really should say which XPath version you are asking about).

It's tricky in XPath 1.0, but you can use the complicated formula that `A except B` can be written `A[not(. | B)]`, so it becomes `//a[not(. | //a[@default='true'][1])]`. Or you could exploit the fact that the nodes all have distinct content, and write `//a[not(. = //a[@default='true'][1])]`.

Comment: My bad. I forgot to mention that I need it to be XPath 1.0.
Thank you for your answer and clean explanation