# How to select nodes by condition EXCEPT the one with specified index

Tags: xml, xpath

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73203307/how-to-select-all-except-first-element-matching-criteria-using-xpath/73203380#73203380) let's say we have XML

```
<root>
  <a default="False">1</a>
  <a default="True">2</a>
  <a default="False">3</a>
  <a default="False">4</a>
  <a default="True">5</a>
  <a default="False">6</a>
  <a default="False">7</a>
</root>
```

I can select *the first node with `@default="True"`* with

```
//a[@default="True"][1]  # node with value "2"
```

the second one with

```
//a[@default="True"][2]  # node with value "5"
```

...but if I want to select all **except the first one**

```
//a[not(self::a[@default="True"][1])]
```

[it excludes both node with value "2" and "5"](https://www.videlibri.de/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&data=%3Croot%3E%0A%20%20%3Ca%20default%3D%22False%22%3E1%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%3Ca%20default%3D%22True%22%3E2%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%3Ca%20default%3D%22False%22%3E3%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%3Ca%20default%3D%22False%22%3E4%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%3Ca%20default%3D%22True%22%3E5%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%3Ca%20default%3D%22False%22%3E6%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%20%20%3Ca%20default%3D%22False%22%3E7%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%3C%2Froot%3E&extract=%2F%2Fa%5Bnot(self%3A%3Aa%5B%40default%3D%22True%22%5D%5B1%5D)%5D&extract-kind=xpath3.1&printed-node-format=html&output-format=adhoc&input-format=auto&dot-notation=unambiguous)

So what's wrong with the last XPath expression? Why it ignores the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select all except the first, use

`//a[@default="True"][position() != 1]`

What's wrong with your expression? Well `self::a` only selects one node, so `self::a[1]` means exactly the same as `self::a`.

Incidentally, using `//a[1]` is usually wrong - it should usually be `(//a)[1]`. It only works in your case because all the `a` elements are siblings at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//a[@default='True'][count(preceding-sibling::a[@default='True'])>0]
```

This expression selects all `a` elements with at least one predecessor matching the given criteria.

---

The explanation why your expression `//a[not(self::a[@default="True"][1])]` doesn't work is simple: *nearly all* `a` elements *do not* satisfy the condition given. The expression selects all `a`s that are not an `a` with the attribute `@default` with the value "True".

Comment: What if there are 3 nodes with `@default="True"` and I want to ignore the second one?

Comment: Then you could use a range like this: `//a[@default='True'][count(preceding-sibling::a[@default='True'])&lt;1 or count(preceding-sibling::a[@default='True'])>1]` which select all elements with index <1 and >1 (respectively with index <2 and >2, because XPath starts counting at 1).